# Fibonacci forever

Tags: java, fibonacci-sequence

I recently wrote a Fibonacci program in Python, and one of the answers mentioned an Infinite Sequence. I decided to implement an infinite sequence in Java, as I am not that experienced in Python.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class InfiniteFibonacci {

    /**
     * The default starting amount of numbers in the sequence to be generated.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_STARTING_CAP = 64;

    private List<SequencePart> parts;

    private int currentSize = 2;

    private BigInteger current = BigInteger.ONE;
    private BigInteger previous = BigInteger.ONE;

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>InfiniteFibonacci</code> object, with the default amount of numbers.
     */
    public InfiniteFibonacci() {
        this(DEFAULT_STARTING_CAP);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>InfiniteFibonacci</code> object, with the specified amount of numbers.
     * 
     * @param startCap The amount of numbers to generate. It will be rounded up to the nearest 16.
     */
    public InfiniteFibonacci(int startCap) {
        parts = new LinkedList<>();
        initFirst();
        initTo(startCap);
    }

    private void initFirst() {
        SequencePart part = new SequencePart();
        part.values[0] = previous;
        part.values[1] = current;
        for (int i = 2; i < SequencePart.SIZE; i++) {
            part.values[i] = previous.add(current);
            previous = current;
            current = part.values[i];
        }
        parts.add(part);
    }

    private void initTo(int index) {
        for (; currentSize <= index; currentSize += SequencePart.SIZE) {
            SequencePart part = new SequencePart();
            for (int i = 0; i < SequencePart.SIZE; i++) {
                part.values[i] = previous.add(current);
                previous = current;
                current = part.values[i];
            }
            parts.add(part);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the <code>n</code>th number in the sequence, zero-based.
     * 
     * @param index the <code>n</code> as described
     * 
     * @return the specified in the sequence, zero-based.
     */
    public BigInteger getNumberAt(int index) {
        if (index > currentSize) {
            initTo(index);
        }
        return parts.get(index / SequencePart.SIZE).values[index % SequencePart.SIZE];
    }

    private class SequencePart {

        private static final int SIZE = 16;

        private BigInteger[] values = new BigInteger[SIZE];

        private SequencePart() {

        }

    }

}
```

Concerns:

1. I don't like the `initFirst()` method, as it is very WET. Is there a way to avoid it?
2. Is my JavaDoc and OOP good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if `SequencePart` is necessary.

It would be *much* simpler to just keep a `List<BigInteger>` of numbers in `InfiniteFibonacci`, unless you've already done the testing to see if your chunked `LinkedList` is faster than a plain `ArrayList<BigInteger>`.

You would end up with something like this:

```
public BigInteger getNth(int index) {
    if (index >= nums.size()) {
        initTo(index);
    }
    return nums[index];
}
```

with no `initFirst` and with a much simpler `initTo(index)` method that just appends to `this.nums` until `index`.

**Edit:** OK, sorry, I realize why you're doing this chunking strategy (cheap insertion at the end of a `LinkedList`). I think it depends on your intended use case, and how often users will request arbitrary Fibs. I would still suggest testing tweaking the size of your `SequenceParts` to see if 16 is the optimum size for your intended usage.

### Iterator

Since this is an *infinite* sequence, I would also suggest exposing an iterator interface that doesn't maintain a cache. If a caller only needs the numbers once, then you can let them iterate through Fibonacci numbers infinitely using **constant space**, as opposed to building up your internal list of calculated numbers.

Comment: Can it really be considered constant space if the numbers are getting bigger (therefore needing more bits to store)?

Comment: @Rodolvertice Asymptotically constant (`O(1)` space) and approximately constant anyway because you're just storing two `BigIntegers`.

Comment: Considering that the Nth Fibonacci number takes O(N) space to store, it really can't be considered constant space. Storing a list of all of them up to the Nth takes O(N^2) space, though.