# Let's "Iterator" through Fibonacci, forever and ever

Tags: java, iterator, fibonacci-sequence

Following-up to my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114501/71574), this class is now based on an iterator. The class, instead of forcing the programmer to use up a bunch of memory just to get each progressive number once, they can now use an iterator. The class itself is also now based on an iterator, which makes *my* life easier too. No more `initFirst()`!

Edit note: the `main` method was there to test, and is there for no other reason.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * 
 */
public class InfiniteFibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfiniteFibonacci i = new InfiniteFibonacci();
        System.out.println(i.getNumberAt(0));
        System.out.println(i.getNumberAt(100));
    }

    /**
     * The default starting amount of numbers in the sequence to be generated.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_STARTING_CAP = 64;

    private final Iterator<BigInteger> iterator = new FibonacciIterator();

    private List<SequencePart> parts;

    private int currentSize = 0;

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>InfiniteFibonacci</code> object, with the default
     * amount of numbers.
     */
    public InfiniteFibonacci() {
        this(DEFAULT_STARTING_CAP);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>InfiniteFibonacci</code> object, with the specified
     * amount of numbers.
     * 
     * @param startCap
     *            The amount of numbers to generate. It will be rounded up to
     *            the nearest 16.
     */
    public InfiniteFibonacci(int startCap) {
        parts = new LinkedList<>();
        initTo(startCap);
    }

    private void initTo(int index) {
        for (; currentSize <= index; currentSize += SequencePart.SIZE) {
            SequencePart part = new SequencePart();
            for (int i = 0; i < SequencePart.SIZE; i++) {
                part.values[i] = iterator.next();
            }
            parts.add(part);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the <code>n</code>th number in the sequence, zero-based.
     * 
     * @param index
     *            the <code>n</code> as described
     * 
     * @return the specified in the sequence, zero-based.
     */
    public BigInteger getNumberAt(int index) {
        if (index > currentSize) {
            initTo(index);
        }
        return parts.get(index / SequencePart.SIZE).values[index
                % SequencePart.SIZE];
    }

    /**
     * Provides a faster <code>Iterator</code> for code that uses only each
     * number once.
     * 
     * @return An <code>Iterator</code> that iterates through each of the
     *         numbers.
     */
    public static Iterator<BigInteger> getIterator() {
        return new FibonacciIterator();
    }

    private class SequencePart {

        private static final int SIZE = 16;

        private BigInteger[] values = new BigInteger[SIZE];

        private SequencePart() {

        }

    }

    private static final class FibonacciIterator implements
            Iterator<BigInteger> {

        private BigInteger current = BigInteger.ONE;
        private BigInteger previous = BigInteger.ZERO;

        private FibonacciIterator() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // Always has next
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public BigInteger next() {
            BigInteger temp = current;
            current = previous.add(current);
            previous = temp;
            return temp;
        }

    }

}
```

Concerns:

1. Was implementing `Iterator<BigInteger>` a good idea?
2. Was the changes an improvement, or was it "poison"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the title of the question and the main class, I expected to see a simple iterator over Fibonacci numbers to infinity. Instead I see a class with too many responsibilities. It would be better to separate these concerns:

- the infinite iterator
- one class to get the `n`th Fibonacci number with caching
- a utility class that implements the cache storage from a linked list of segments, the logic of which is encapsulated and hidden from users
- the runner class with the main method

The `Iterator<BigInteger>` is a very good idea. I thought of perhaps providing an `Iterator<Integer>` too, but then, Fibonacci numbers tend to get very big very fast, so there's probably not much point. So just the `Iterator<BigInteger>` makes sense.

What you did with the sequence parts is an interesting way to implement a dynamically growing array-like storage without resize operations. As mentioned, this has nothing to do with Fibonacci numbers, and this logic could live in its own utility class. But I think it's probably not worth it. You can use a simple `ArrayList` instead. When the performance of the `ArrayList` becomes a real concern, you could try your alternative `List` implementation.